What does "acceptable" refer to in Romans 12:2?
Romans 12:2 ESV

"Do not be conformed to this world, but be transformed  by the renewal of your mind, that by testing you may discern what is the will of God, what is good and acceptable and perfect."  [acceptable/euareston; eu/well; aresko/pleasing].

A. Does "acceptable" here refer to Christians being well pleased because having learnt to discern God's will they are pleased to submit to it?
B. Does "acceptable" refer to God being well pleased because His will brings about that which is well pleasing to Himself? [Ro 12:1 "a living sacrifice, holy and acceptable to God"].
C. Another explanation.

The word acceptable in Romans 12:2 is actually not an adjective but a noun, made so by the substantivizing effect of the article.
Romans 12:2
τὸ    ἀγαθὸν     καὶ     εὐάρεστον     καὶ   τέλειον
the   good       and     acceptable    and   perfect

Furthermore, that the article is not repeated before each word indicates that the three should be considered as one in this context.
Meyer’s NT Commentary

The repetition of the article was the less necessary, as the three
adjectives used substantivally exhaust one notion (that of moral
good), and that climactically. Comp. Winer, p. 121 [E. T. 159];
Dissen, ad Dem. de cor. p. 373 f.; Kühner, II. 1, p. 528.

In my opinion, that the words “good,” “acceptable,” and “perfect” are nouns not adjectives significantly impacts meaning. Adjectives are subjective descriptors. For something to be considered as good, acceptable or perfect depends on a person’s opinion or point of view, one with which others may agree or disagree. And because of the common tendency of humans to change their minds, what seems good to a person one day may not appear so to them the next.
Saying that something is good, however, is very different from saying that something exemplifies the good. The use of the article before “good and acceptable and perfect” takes these three words and turns them into one objective reality. But for such a reality to exist, there needs to be a fixed reference point, one that does not depend on the varied and unstable whims of human nature. Romans 12:2 presents us with that unchanging point of reference.
Placed in apposition to the will of God, “the good and acceptable and perfect” does not describe what pleases men. Nor does it just modify/describe what pleases God. Instead, the appositional construction sets the will of God as the unchanging standard for identifying what is objectively good, acceptable, and perfect.
Romans 12:2 YLT

and be not conformed to this age, but be transformed by the renewing
of your mind, for your proving what is the will of God -- the good,
and acceptable, and perfect.


Romans 12:1 NKJV

I beseech you therefore, brethren, by the mercies of God, that you
present your bodies a living sacrifice, holy, acceptable to God,
which is your reasonable service.

As Bibleref says: he urges us to learn how to look at life with a new question: What does God want for me? What is truly a good, acceptable, and perfect use of my life for His purposes and not just for my own?
“acceptable” (euareston in Greek) is generally understood to refer to what is pleasing or acceptable to God.
According to Ellicott's Commentary:

“Acceptable,” that is to say, to God Himself.

This verse is part of Paul’s exhortation to believers not to conform to the patterns of this world, but to be transformed by the renewal of their minds. This transformation enables believers to discern and do the will of God, which is described as "good and acceptable and perfect".
So, in response to your options:
A. It’s true that Christians may find joy and satisfaction in discerning and doing God’s will, the primary focus of “acceptable” seems to be, in this context, on what is pleasing to God, not necessarily on the believer’s feelings of satisfaction. Although, I believe it could be taken this way, it is typically not.
I quote from Vincent's Word Studies: Better to render the three adjectives as appositional. "May prove what is the will of God, what is good," etc. The other rendering compels us to take well-pleasing in the sense of agreeable to men.
B. “acceptable” seems to refer to what is pleasing to God, aligning with His will and His standards. So this option makes sense.
Barnes' Notes agrees with this notion:

Acceptable - That which will be pleasing to God. or which he will
approve. There is scarcely a more difficult text in the Bible than
this, or one that is more full of meaning. It involves the main duty
of religion to be separated from the world; and expresses the way in
which that duty may be performed, and in which we may live so as to
ascertain and do the will of God. If all Christians would obey this,
religion would be everywhere honored. If all would separate from the
vices and follies, the amusements and gaieties of the world, Christ
would be glorified. If all were truly renewed in their minds, they
would lose their relish for such things, and seeking only to do the
will of God, they would not be slow to find it.

Another explanation could be that “acceptable” refers to what is morally and ethically right, in line with God’s character and commands. However, this would still ultimately point back to what is pleasing to God.

Nice answer! Because we are accepted by God upon having faith, our reasonable service is to now act worthy of our calling as being "ambassadors for Christ", not according to our works, but rather as ministers of the truth regarding God's grace and faith. 2 Tim 1:9 "Who hath saved us, and called us with an holy calling, not according to our works, but according to his own purpose and grace, which was given us in Christ Jesus before the world began," 2 Cor 5:20 "Now then we are ambassadors for Christ, as though God did beseech you by us: we pray you in Christ's stead, be ye reconciled to God."

This exhortation is addressed to Christians - to those who have already come to spiritual life, 'born from above' by the Spirit of Christ indwelling them. Their renewal has begun, and is in progress. And now they can intelligently understand things of God that are a mystery, if not utterly unknown, to those who do not belong to Christ. This is all part of delighting to find out, and to do, the will of God.
Context shows that Christians desire to grasp what pleases God, not themselves, and this is where an older translation than the one used in the question is helpful. Context requires taking into account the previous verses, which say, in part:

"O depths of riches, and wisdom and knowledge of God! How unsearchable
His judgments, and untraceable His ways! For who did know the mind of
the Lord? Or who did become His counsellor?... I call upon you,
therefore, brethren, through the compassions of God, to present your
bodies a sacrifice - living, sanctified, acceptable to God - your
intelligent service; and be not conformed to this age, but be
transformed by the renewing of your mind, for your proving what [is]
the will of God - the good, and acceptable, and perfect." Young's
Literal Translation Romans 11:33-34 & 12:1-2 [Emphases mine]

Yet an important point remains to be made, even though context is totally clear that "acceptable" refers to what is acceptable to God. This relates to what the renewing of the mind of the Christian means. Many people suppose they are to change their own mind - they are to think differently - without grasping that the scriptures present an utterly drastic event before they can begin to plumb the depths of knowing the mind of God with regard to his perfect and acceptable will.
Paul spoke of this in his letter to Corinthian Christians. He first explained the impossibility of "the natural man" ever knowing the mind of God. Then he told those Christians, "but to us did God reveal [them] through his Spirit, for the Spirit all things doth search, even the depths of God..." (1 Cor. 2:10, YLT) Then he assured them that "the spiritual" discern such things, for although they cannot know the mind of the Lord so as to instruct him, "we - we have the mind of Christ." (2:14-16).
The Greek word, metanoia is used. It does not mean a changed mind, but a new mind. Our old mind must be replaced with the mind of Christ, and that is a work of the Holy Spirit. The point is that no Christian can have a changed mind without first receiving this new mind - the mind of Christ. To put it the other way around, an individual can, indeed, change their mind about many things, matters of belief and how to live better etc, but that will never result in them being gifted by the Holy Spirit the mind of Christ. That has to happen first before the depths of God's will can start to be plumbed, and thus discovering God's perfect will, which is acceptable to him. Those with such a new mind will delight to discover, and to do, God's will, as did Christ, for they now have the mind of Christ.
The question does not ask about 1 Corinthians 15:45, but it is necessary substantiation for the claim that Romans 12:2 means it is what is acceptable to God that is meant.
